# How to change data augmentation parameters dynamically in the config file of Tensorflow Object Detection pipelines?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, config, object-detection-api

I am trying to create an object detection framework which takes input from user and creates custom object detection models based on the user selection.
For this I have to dynamically make some changes in the config files based on the model ,the hyperparameters and the augmentation options selected by the user.
So far I am able to change some parameters from the pipeline.config files but when it comes to data augmentation I am not able to make any changes in those fields.
Does anyone know how can we make changes to the data augmentation parameters using python scripts, dynamically given the user  input.
How can we add more options to it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2


def main():
    pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()

    with tf.gfile.GFile("ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config", "r") as f:
        proto_str = f.read()
        text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.height = 300
    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.width = 300
    pipeline_config.model.ssd.num_classes = 2


    pipeline_config.train_config.batch_size = 1
    pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options[0]['keypoint_flip_permutation'] = 1

    config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config)
    with tf.gfile.Open('pipeline.config', "wb") as f:
        f.write(config_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the above code I am getting this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/test.py:11: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/test.py", line 21, in main
    pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options[0]['keypoint_flip_permutation'] = 1
TypeError: 'PreprocessingStep' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a guess that I posted on [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) because I accidentally confused it with this page:

---

I'm very new to programming but I wanted to share something that I was trying to do because the original question also gives me trouble.

Let's say I already have a config file on my computer and I've compiled all of my TF2 Object Detection protos but now I want to change the preprocessing. I use python.

First, I'll get my config file as a python dictionary

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util

# PATH_TO_MY_CONFIG_FILE can be whatever the path is to your config file 
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_MY_CONFIG_FILE)
```

Next, I'd like to check what data augmentations / preprocessing I currently have.

```
print(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options)
print(type(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options[0]))
```

> [random_horizontal_flip {
> }
> , random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
> output_size: 512
> scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
> scale_max: 2.0
> }
> ]

> <class 'object_detection.protos.preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep'>

It looks to me like *configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options* is a python list containing instances of the class *PreprocessingStep* that is from the file *preprocessor_pb2.py*

When I previously tried running code from the TF2 Object Detection github repo there was some code that compiled protos for me. The protocompiler took my preprocessor.proto file and created a new file from it called preprocessor_pb2.py that is now on my computer. In this python file there is a class called *PreprocessingStep*.

I will use this script to make a new preprocessing step for my configuration.

```
from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2

# Construct a new PreprocessingStep object
my_new_data_augmentation = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
# I would like to randomly change some color images to gray with %20 probability
my_new_data_augmentation.random_rgb_to_gray.probability = 0.2
print(my_new_data_augmentation)
```

> random_rgb_to_gray {
> probability: 0.20000000298023224
> }

A PreprocessingStep step object has a lot of different fields. You can look inside the file *preprocessor_pb2.py* for a list of fields you can modify or you can look at the [preprocessor.proto on the TF2 OD Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) at the list of messages (These are the text in red). The messages are the names of the fields you can change.

Once you've selected a field to modify you can further set the optional parameters. In my example 'probability' is the only parameter you can modify for the 'random_rgb_to_gray' preprocessing step (I think).

Also, I don't think you can set your PreprocessingStep object to have multiple preprocessing fields. For example, if I did

```
my_new_data_augmentation.random_rgb_to_gray.probability = 0.2
my_new_data_augmentation.random_adjust_hue.max_delta = 0.1
print(my_new_data_augmentation)
```

> random_adjust_hue {
> max_delta: 0.10000000149011612
> }

things will just get overwritten.

I guess, now my preprocessing step is random_adjust_hue. I will go ahead and add this to my data augmentations now using list.append()

```
configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options.append(my_new_data_augmentation)
print(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options)
```

> [random_horizontal_flip {
> }
> , random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
> output_size: 512
> scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
> scale_max: 2.0
> }
> , random_adjust_hue {
> max_delta: 0.10000000149011612
> }
> ]

Now I can save my configs using the usual config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs() method.

Like I said I'm very new to programming and I don't know if this idea causes some bugs that I'm not aware of but I wanted to share this in case somebody else finds this helpful as a starting place to build on I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Whatev's answer (Thanks Whatevs! Your answer helped a lot.):

At the step of copying a pre-trained model's pipeline.config and editing it, here is the complete code of customizing it, inclusive of adding additional image augmentation steps:

(I'm also quite new to this, so perhaps my method may not be the proper way, but it worked for me, and hopefully might help anyone having the same issue)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2

config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])

pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'], "r") as f:
    proto_str = f.read()
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

pipeline_config.model.ssd.num_classes = len(labels)
pipeline_config.train_config.batch_size = 4
pipeline_config.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint = os.path.join(paths['PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH'], PRETRAINED_MODEL_NAME, 'checkpoint', 'ckpt-0')
pipeline_config.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "detection"
pipeline_config.train_input_reader.label_map_path= files['LABELMAP']
pipeline_config.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = [os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')]
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].label_map_path = files['LABELMAP']
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = [os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')]

##? ADD IMAGE AUGMENTATION PREPROCESSING STEPS:
# see params here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto

# default copied pre-trained model's pipeline config already contains the following:

    #   data_augmentation_options {
    #     random_horizontal_flip {
    #     }
    #   }
    #   data_augmentation_options {
    #     random_crop_image {
    #       min_object_covered: 0.0
    #       min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
    #       max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
    #       min_area: 0.75
    #       max_area: 1.0
    #       overlap_thresh: 0.0
    #     }
    #   }

# We will append the following augmentation steps (skipping random_horizontal_flip and random_crop_image):

augm = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
augm.random_vertical_flip.probability = 0.4
pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options.append(augm)

augm = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
augm.random_adjust_brightness.max_delta  = 0.2
pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options.append(augm)

augm = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
augm.random_adjust_contrast.max_delta  = 0.2
pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options.append(augm)

augm = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
augm.random_rotation90.probability  = 0.5
pipeline_config.train_config.data_augmentation_options.append(augm)


config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config)

with tf.io.gfile.GFile(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'], "wb") as f:
    f.write(config_text)
```